# Hololens Emulator - Unity application always sleeping?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, hololens, hololens-emulator

When opening an application from the Hololens after the initial successful deploy run, the program no longer runs and instead displays that it is sleeping as such:

[image]

This is repeatable if I do the following steps:

1. Deploy to Emulator (without debugging)
2. Let the Emulator run the game automatically (the game works fine at this point)
3. Bloom Gesture to exit the game
4. Bloom Gesture to the menu and place and run my game (therefore resuming the game)
5. Bloom Gesture to exit game and remove the window (therefore killing the game)
6. Run the game again

At that point the window will only stay sleeping and the program will not run. Even when I close the emulator and deploy it again!!
My only current hotfix at the moment is to delete the certificates generated in Unity asset folders so that they are remade when I build the application again. At that point the emulator thinks it is a new program and it runs properly (but only the first time)

My current setup:

- Unity 2017.1.0f3
- Visual Studio 2017 (with all required extensions)
- Hololens Emulator build 10.0.14393.1358

This issue has occurred with many different unity programs including the most basic ones (no scripts). So I assume something is wrong with my unity setup, my visual studio setup, or it is a bug in the emulator.

This has only been a problem on the emulator. Not the actual device  (it works on the device). If you need to know how I setup my Unity project or Visual Studio project I will edit this and post this.

Comment: I haven't run into this issue in the short time I had working with the HoloLens, afraid I can't help.